# Список слов русского языка

Tags: общие-вопросы

Где можно скачать электронный список слов русского языка (разумеется, не только существительных) без каких-либо сопровождающих комментариев (характеристик, значений, частоты употребления)?

Желательно, чтобы каждое слово в списке начиналось с новой строки.

Comment: Купите орфографический словарь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот](http://speakrus.ru/dict/index.htm) что я нашёл, загуглив это.